# svn bluehost checkout

Tags: svn, bluehost

I am trying to setup svn version control on my bluehost web hosting account. I created the repository my typing:

```
svnadmin create my_repo
```

I have a folder at the same level labeled public_html, that is the folder I want to do version control on. Can someone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: You should add some information what bluehost web hosting provided. Are you able to install something? Is subversion preinstalled by bluehost? Is a web server (Apache?) preinstalled? What is the operating system you are working on? The question is broad open, so I don't think there will be a short answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you want to add the folder `public_html` (and its contents possibly) to the subversion repository `my_repo` that you created.

You can use [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import) for this.

> svn import /path/to/public_html url-of-my_repo

Once this is done, as documented, you should delete public_html (which is still unversioned) and checkout a fresh copy of it from my_repo.

Comment: I actually went into the public_html directory and did a checkout with the "." char at the end. "cd public_html/" "svn checkout /home/name/my_repo ." The dot (".") is what I was missing and screwing me up. I'm sure it will work with the import also. Thanks.